# When is a real number algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

By definition - A real number is algebraic if it is a root of a non-zero polynomial equation with rational coefficients. What does non-zero polynomial equation mean?

Well, an equation f(x) = x -5, becomes zero when x = 5, so this is a zero polynomial equation. Is the definition saying that the equation should not equal zero in any case?

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Non zero polynomial equation means that that the polynomial in this equation is not identically equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zero polynomial is a polynomial which gives $0$ for all values of $x$,

Basically $P(x)=0$ means that no matter what $x$ you put in there, the result will always be zero. For your example,
$P(x)=x-5$ is not a zero polynomial because there is only a finite number of $x$'s for which the polynomial will be $0$. In this case there is only one such $x$. And that is $5$.

And a real number is algebraic if there exists a non-$\color{green}{\textrm{constant}}$ polynomial with rational coefficients, such that the the real number is one of the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing insight. I tried upvoting but I don't have enough points. damn.

Comment: @Sunny. You can click the ✔ button under the downvote button to select my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_0(x):=0$ be the ZERO-POLYNOMIAL.

If we not avoid this pathological case, then every real number would be algebraic, since every real number is a "solution" of the equation $P_0(x)=0$ (even $\pi$ or $e$).